# InstrumentedAttribute vs Column in update() clause in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a simple ORM defined,

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sql.Column(sql.String)
```

What are the differences between the two approaches below to update a row?

Approach 1

```
connection.execute(
    User.__table__.update()
    .where(User.name='Alice')
    .values(name='Bob')
)
```

Approach 2

```
connection.execute(
    User.__table__.update()
    .where(User.__table__.c.name='Alice')  # <-- Difference
    .values(name='Bob')
)
```

`User.name` is a `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute`, while `User.__table__.c.name` is a `sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column`

I found [SqlAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes) using the second approach, but is the first approach valid too?

Comment: They're effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably not exhaustive, but I noticed at least one difference:

**In the approach #1:** the key will be an object where `__repr__()` will show something like `<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f03e93b77c0>`.

This can be problematic in unit-tests, for example when using a mock and `assert_called_with()` fails.
In this case, you'll get something like:

```
AssertionError: expected call not found.
Expected: some_db_method({<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a940e0>: 1, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a94400>: <ANY>, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a945e0>: "something", <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a94180>: None}, {<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a945e0>: <ANY>})
Actual: some_db_method(<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a940e0>: 1, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a94400>: <ANY>, <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a945e0>: "something", <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fed04a94180>: None}, {<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x8fef13a123f5>: <ANY>})
```

Which can be harder to read and debug.

If you still prefer the approach #2, there is still a way to show the columns in a more user-friendly way:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import InstrumentedAttribute

def _debug_columns_repr(self: InstrumentedAttribute):
    return f"{self.table.name}.{self.name}"

InstrumentedAttribute.__repr__ = _debug_columns_repr
```